# Do I need to use WebSockets to interface node.js with PhantomJS?

Tags: node.js, websocket, phantomjs

I couldn't find it referenced in the documentation but since PhantomJs is now at 2.1, Is there a way to use a WebSocket to interface NodeJs and PhantomJs directly or am I better going with StdIn/StdOut?

I'd like to skip the step of spawning a webserver plus a fake webpage to catch the events like I've seen on many github. If I can I would avoid those ninja tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need WebSockets or the Web Server module.

There are basically two ways to use PhantomJS from node.js:

- Write a plain PhantomJS script and spawn a PhantomJS process that executes that script, but this doesn't provide easy interactivity
- Interface with PhantomJS through the *many* available bridges so that you can mix PhantomJS code with node.js code:
  [phantom](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node), [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom), [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) (version <1.8 used PhantomJS, now it's Electron), [Horseman](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman), [navit](https://github.com/nodeca/navit), [phridge](https://github.com/peerigon/phridge), [node-phantom-simple](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple), [jquery.go.js](https://github.com/travist/jquery.go.js), [SpookyJS](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS) (wrapper around CasperJS, which is a wrapper around PhantomJS), [Selenium-Webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) (JavaScript bindings), [webdriver.io](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio) (other JS bindings for Selenium), etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Electron, seems to be doing what I'm looking for My end goal is to produce automated daily reports into png out of a html/javascript charts and tables.

Comment: Ended up using Electron which is doing exactly what I need.